# how to find key-value pair that contains same value or superset of a value

Tags: python, key-value

`d = {1: ['a'], 3: ['b','c'], 4: ['a','d'], 5: ['b','c','d']}`, this is just an example. I have a large file of such key-values pair. My question is how can I find values that is present in multiple key-value pair. I want to fetch that key-value pair. For this example, the first value corresponding to key `1` is `'a'` and it is present in `4:['a','d']`, so I want to fetch `4: ['a', 'd']` pair.

Note that, I have a huge dictionary containing over millions entries.

Comment: Why `4: ['a', 'd']` and not `1: ['a']`?

Comment: and how do you want your key value pair to be returned as ?

Comment: because I want to get other than itself. Means, each key-values pair will be compared to rest of the key-values except itself.

Comment: My output should be like: key: [values], or more precisely list of key-values.

Comment: you need 1: [ 'a']  or not?

Comment: Also `['b','c','d']` is a superset of `['b','c']`, why is it not in the output?

Comment: 5: ['b','c','d'] it shoule be in the output when it will compared to 3: ['b', 'c']

Answer (score 0):

I guess this could fit your case :

```py
def findInDict(d, element):
    l = []
    for x, i in d.items():
        if element in i:
            l.append((x, i))
    return l
```

(feed it your dict as `d` and the element you want to find key value pairs of as `element`)

Example :

`findInDict({1: ['a'], 3: ['b','c'], 4: ['a','d'], 5: ['b','c','d']}, "a")`

will return you

`[(1, ['a']), (4, ['a', 'd'])]`

Answer (score 0):

Using List comprehension you can achieve this

```
def findData(d, findvalue):
     return [(i,v) for i , v in d.items() if findvalue in v ]
```

```
text = 'a'
print(findData(d,text))
```